# Relative `parentElement`

Tags: javascript, dom

Suppose I have a `table`, some `rows` and `cells`.
If I click a cell and I need to go to the `table` node I can do something like:

```
while (tcel) {
  if (tcel.nodeName === "TABLE") {
    tbl = tcel;
    break;
  }
  else {
    tcel = tcel.parentElement;
     // tcel will be lost
  }
}
```

I'm wondering if there's a way I can get to the `table` node without the loop, but instead if there's a method that `knows` that the `tcel` belongs to the `table`, like a `relative parent`?

Comment: have you tried using [`closest`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `.closest` to find an ancestor node that matches a particular selector:

```
const tbl = tcel.closest('table');
```

If no element is found, it will be `null`.